# Jekyll: need all hrefs to be relative or start from server.domain

Tags: jekyll, mod-proxy

I have a jekyll local website that hopefully will be made public. The only way for me to do so is to use mod_proxy on apache2. Unfortunately only the main page works correctly. Others are not forwarded, because the links Jekyll creates look like:

```
<a href=/mysite/2015/07/17/About/>About</a></li>
```

I need them to be either relative, i.e. or to be really absolute, i.e.:

```
<a href=http://my.server.com/mysite/2015/07/17/About/>About</a></li>
```

Only in that case mod_proxy will be able to substitute `http://my.server.com/mysite` with `localhost:4000/mysite`

Now, links done by Jekyll that start with `/` are dispached as they would be served by the main website i.e. the one hosted on  `http://my.server.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your _config.yml file, you can set your base url like the following:

```
url: http://www.example.com
```

You can call this variable later using liquid markup:

```
<a href="{{ site.url }}/path-to-your-stuff"></a>
```

And you have an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

The `/mysite` part of url is the `baseurl` configuration parameter, found in `_config.yml`.

A relative link is now :

```
<a href={{site.baseurl}}/2015/07/17/About/>About</a></li>
```

An an absolute link is now :

```
<a href={{site.url}}{{site.baseurl}}/2015/07/17/About/>About</a></li>
```